# QT Ruby bindings signal-slot with hash param

Tags: ruby, qt, signals-slots

Im using qtbindings for Ruby (https://github.com/ryanmelt/qtbindings)
and i would emit a signal with an hash param...

Something like this:

```
require 'Qt'

class Foo < Qt::Object

  signals 'my_signal(Hash)'
  slots 'my_slot(Hash)'

  def initialize(parent = nil)
    super(parent)
    connect(self, SIGNAL('my_signal(Hash)'), self, SLOT('my_slot(Hash)'))
  end

  def emit_my_signal
    emit my_signal({:foo => :bar})
  end

  def my_slot(hash)
    puts hash.inspect
  end
end

o = Foo.new
o.emit_my_signal
```

If I run this script I get the error: `Cannot handle 'Hash' as slot
argument (ArgumentError).`
If I use `int` instead of `Hash` everything is fine.

There is a way to do this?? How?

Thanks.

Comment: I've checked also http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Ruby#Emitting_Ruby_Classes but seems dont work for me...

Comment: Richard Dale suggest me to use `const QMap<QString,QVariant>&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution:
pass the string of the Ruby Object ID... Not use the ID as Fixnum because Ruby Fixnum objects may be up to 62 bits, but C ints are 32 bit.
When you get the object id you can try to retrieve the object with `ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id_as_string.to_i)`.

My solution code:

```
require 'Qt'

class Foo < Qt::Object

  signals 'my_signal(const QString&)'
  slots 'my_slot(const QString&)'

  def initialize(parent = nil)
    super(parent)
    connect(self, SIGNAL('my_signal(const QString&)'), self, SLOT('my_slot(const QString&)'))
  end

  def emit_my_signal
    emit my_signal({:foo => :bar}.object_id.to_s)
  end

  def my_slot(object_id)
    hash = ObjectSpace._id2ref(object_id.to_i)
    puts hash.inspect
  end
end

o = Foo.new
o.emit_my_signal
```

May be that the garbage collector go to destroy the hash object and the attempt to retrieve the object fail...